# TFS Build - How to deploy to Multiple locations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

How to deploy (copy the application files) to multiple locations when TFS build is executed.

See the picture when ever build is initiated I am copying to a location, I wanted to give multiple location in MSBuild Arguments.

[image]

```
MSBuild Arguments : /p:DeployPath=\\ServerName\C$\Inetpub\wwwroot\ApplicationName
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another [`CopyDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265783%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Activity_CopyDirectory) activity to your build process template XAML.

```
<mtbwa:CopyDirectory DisplayName="Drop Files to Drop Location" Source="[BinariesDirectory]" Destination="[DropLocation]" />
```

Or, use MSBuild [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) task in the last scipt being run in the build (AKA post-build script).